# Form of a prime dividing a certain difference of two prime powers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ and $q$ be odd primes.

If $q|(a^p-1)$  then,

either $q|(a-1)$ or $q=(2rp+1)$

for some integer $r$.

Comment: See theorem $\#3$ of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime#Theorems_about_Mersenne_numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $q\mid (a^p-1) $ we have $$a^p\equiv 1 \pmod{q}\tag{1}$$

Since the order of $a$ modulo $q$ must divide $p$, the order must be either $1$ or $p$. If the order is $1$ then we get $a\equiv 1 \pmod{q}$. If the order is $p$ then $p$ must divide $\phi(q)$ : $$p\mid \phi(q)$$ $$p\mid (q-1)$$ $$q = pt+1$$

$q$ is odd only when $t$ is even :
$$q=2pr+1$$

Answer (score 0):

p and q being odd primes 
p = qt + 1 
P  = 2qr + 1

Comment: Then what is the use of given condition